# python contextmanager newline issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, contextmanager

Using Python's [contextmanager](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) I want to generate a wrapper to display Linux-like progress of a certain block of code:

`Doing something... done. [42 ms]`

This is working - kind of:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import time

@contextmanager
def msg(m):
    print(m + "... ", end='')
    t_start = time.time()
    yield
    t_duration_ms = 1000 * (time.time() - t_start)
    print("done. [{:.0f} ms]".format(t_duration_ms))
```

This usage example should print *"Doing something... "* without a line break, wait for a second, print *"done. [1000 ms]"* including a line break and quit.

```
with msg("Doing something"):
    time.sleep(1)
```

However, when running the snippet, the output *first* waits for a second, and *afterwards* prints the whole line. When removing `end=''` at the first `print()` statement everything works as expected, but at the cost of an ugly output.

Why is this the case, is this intended, and what could be done to avoid this behavior?

*(Python 3.4.0 on Linux Mint 17.1)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is probably due to buffering of `stdout`. You need to manually flush it for the message to be displayed. In Python 3.3+, the [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#print) function has a `flush` argument:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import time

@contextmanager
def msg(m):
    print(m + "... ", end='', flush=True)
    t_start = time.time()
    yield
    t_duration_ms = 1000 * (time.time() - t_start)
    print("done. [{:.0f} ms]".format(t_duration_ms))
```

Prior to 3.3, you would have to use the `flush` method of `stdout`:

```
print(m + "... ", end='')
sys.stdout.flush()
```