# Python - Print script running time: each 1 or 10 minute

Tags: python, performance, function, time, minute

I'm running scripts that take 10-80 minutes. I would like to be able to print the script running time each 1/5/10 minutes ( as i choose).

For example i have a script where i'm creating tables and inserting data to a DB and want to measure the time through the script.

So lets say i have some printing msgs like 
`"Table 1 has been created"` , `"Data inserted to Table 2"` etc.

Between those msgs i want to add like:
`The script is running for 1 minutes`
`The script is running for 2 minutes`
`The script is running for 3 minutes`
Etc...

Someone know what is the best practice for it ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You might take a look at the contextmanager as described in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30828495/3991125).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects):

```
from datetime import datetime
#at the start of the script:
start_time = datetime.now()
# ... some stuff ...
# when you want to print the time elapsed so far:
now_time = datetime.now()
print(now_time - start_time)
```

(of course you can reformat the printing as you wish)

Comment: Hey, This is not bad. BUT, I wanted to run it parallel to the script and print the time each 10 min, and not only when i write `print (time calculation)`